# Opposite of an undercategory

Tags: category-theory

For a category $\mathcal{C}$ and $*$ a terminal object of it, let $\mathcal{C}_*$ denote the category under this terminal object.

Suppose that the opposite of $\mathcal{C}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\simeq \mathcal{D}$. Is it true that $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}_*\simeq \mathcal{D_*}$?

Comment: To be clear, $\mathcal{C}_*^{op}$ means $(\mathcal{C}_*)^{op}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, it does!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite-you have to switch to $D$ over $*$. Given any $X$ in a category $C$, $(X/C)^{op}$ has object the maps $X\to c$ in $C$ and morphisms $(X\to c)\to(X\to c')$ maps
$c'\to c$ in $C$ making the triangle commute in $C$. Alternatively, write the objects as maps $c\to X$ in $C^{op}$ and similarly for the morphisms, and you have an isomorphism $(X/C)^{op}\cong C^{op}/X$.

Comment: Thanks. Just so that I make sure I understand this. Say $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of finite sets, hence $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ is the category of finite Boolean algebras. So $\mathcal{C}_*^{\text{op}}$ is not the category of pointed finite Boolean algebras, but rather what could be called "co-pointed" finite Boolean algebras?

Comment: @mariobenet: yes, that's right, it's the category of pairs of a finite Boolean algebra $B$ and a morphism from $B$ to the two-element Boolean algebra. You might call these augmented Boolean algebras.